# What is the difference between iText's getPageN() and getPageNRelease() calls?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've wondered this for awhile.  There are two calls in PdfReader for getting a page dictionary:  getPageN() and getPageNRelease().

Under which circumstances should we use one or the other?

Are there performance implications of one or the other?

For example, I have an algorithm that is iterating each page in an existing PDF and reading data from it.  Which call should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primarily, if you want to change the page object you retrieve expecting the change not to be volatile (but to appear e.g. in the output of a `PdfStamper` you are going to apply to the `PdfReader` in question), you should use `getPageN()`. If you retrieve the page only to read information from it, you should use `getPageNRelease()`.

---

*And what is the difference?* Well, first of all there only is a difference if you have a `PdfReader` instance running in partial mode, i.e. if it has not parsed the whole PDF on startup but only those objects required for a basic understanding of the PDF in question. Otherwise, i.e. if the PDF has been completely parsed, both methods effectively do the same.

If working in this mode,

- a page you retrieve using `PdfReader.getPageN()` is added to an internal cache; thus, if you query the same page again later, you will retrieve the identical object including all changes you have applied, and so does a `PdfStamper` operating on this reader;
- but a page you retrieve using `PdfReader.getPageNRelease()` immediately after retrieval is removed from that cache again (unless the page had already before been retrieved and added to that cache).

This is done because you usually use the partial mode to minimize the part of the PDF in memory. Thus, if you retrieve a page just to read something from it, the objects the page consists of can be removed from memory again as soon you are finished reading the information you need.

But please do not count on a page read via `PdfReader.getPageNRelease()` being volatile: It isn't if the partial mode is not used, if the page had already been retrieved before using `PdfReader.getPageN()`, or if `PdfReader.setTampered()` has been called before.

---

The partial mode can be activated by using one of the following constructors

```
public PdfReader(final RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, final byte ownerPassword[]) throws IOException

public PdfReader(final RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, final byte ownerPassword[], boolean partial)

public PdfReader(final String filename, final byte ownerPassword[], boolean partial) throws IOException
```

and (in the case of the latter two) using a `partial` parameter value `true`. No other constructors allows to select the partial mode.

---

The OP asked in a comment

> we are using partial mode. Does getPageN() followed later by a call to reader.releasePage() have the same effect?

*Yes, maybe.*

**Yes**, because `getPageNRelease()` is implemented like this

```
public PdfDictionary getPageNRelease(final int pageNum) {
    PdfDictionary dic = getPageN(pageNum);
    pageRefs.releasePage(pageNum);
    return dic;
}
```

and `releasePage()` like this

```
public void releasePage(final int pageNum) {
    pageRefs.releasePage(pageNum);
}
```

Thus, `getPageNRelease()` effectively is the same as `getPageN` plus `releasePage()`.

**Maybe**, because you should not wait too long between those method calls. In particular you should not request yet another page in the meantime because only the most recently fetched page can be released.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - we are using partial mode.  Does getPageN() followed later by a call to reader.releasePage() have the same effect?

Comment: I just answered that in an appendix to my answer.